# Webscraping Tabledata with Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the bonds table from the following link:
https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-28&dateIssue.max=2022-09-28

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Ijh.png

My code at the moment:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-28&dateIssue.max=2022-09-28'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all(class_ = "bsg-table bsg-table--tablesaw tablesaw-swipe")

print(table)
```

when ran I get the empty list.
From this I am not entirely sure what is going wrong , so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

view-source:https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-28&dateIssue.max=2022-09-28

I can't find any instances in that source of the class you are looking for

Using existing classes returns a result set: eg.

```
table = soup.find_all(class_ = "bsg-btn")
```